# std::enable_if with sizeof compile hack

Tags: c++, c++17

Not sure how the `sizeof(Input)` in the below code makes it compile. I think there is some comma operator magic in there too but not sure. I know `SFINAE` needs to happen in immediate context, which is what I do with `typename F = T` but not sure why `(A)` works while `(B)` fails.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct Test {
    
    template <typename Input,typename F = T, enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<F,int>, bool>* = nullptr>
    // template <typename Input, enable_if_t<(sizeof(Input),std::is_same_v<T,int>), bool>* = nullptr> // Works, but how? (A)
    // template <typename Input, enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,int>, bool>* = nullptr> (B)
    void func(Input a) {
        cout << "INT" << endl;
    }
    
    template <typename Input,typename F = T, enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<F,int>, bool>* = nullptr>
    //  template <typename Input, enable_if_t<(sizeof(Input),!std::is_same_v<T,int>), bool>* = nullptr> // Works, but how? (A)
    //  template <typename Input, enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T,int>, bool>* = nullptr> // Doesnt work (B)
    void func(Input a) {
        cout << "NON INT" << endl;
    }
};


int main(){
    Test<int> t;
    t.func(5);
}
```

Wandbox: https://wandbox.org/permlink/9YQwLYs7B69iP2eb

Comment: The full expression `(sizeof(Input),std::is_same_v<T,int>)` does depends on the immediate context, and the `operator,` forces the evaluation of the expression to happen from left to right in order. With that it mind it seem reasonable, even if still somewhat surprising.

Comment: I tried this code snippet, actually both A and B works, could you post the error msg displayed for you?

Comment: @super how does the `operator ,` make (A) work and (B) not work ?

Comment: @PYA I think Jarods answer here is spot on. So it doesn't make it work, it just manages to hide the fact that it's ill-formed from the compiler. It seems you understnad why (B) fails. The difference compared to (A) is that the expression can't be evaluated until the function is instatiated, since it needs to know what `Input` is.

Comment: @super thanks! So the reason why sizeof(Input) makes it work is that it makes the compiler aware of what the type of Input is?

Comment: @PYA Templates are evaluated in multiple passes. It's evaluated once before instatiation, and then again after instatiation. All the things that can be evaluated before instatiation will be. The things that can't, will be evaluated after. Since `Input` is part of the immediate context it can't be evaluated before instatiation.

Comment: So when we only have `std::is_same_v<T,int>` as in (B), the compiler can clearly see that this can be evaluated before instatiation. When you instead make the expression `(sizeof(Input),std::is_same_v<T,int>)`, if the compiler start trying to evaluate this it will see `Input`, which it doesn't know what it is. So evaluation will have to be prosponed until after instatiation.

Comment: It could theoretically figure out that `(sizeof(Input),std::is_same_v<T,int>)` will always be false, but it's clearly not as trivial. In this case it doesn't. It also doesn't have to, since the language forbids that kind of construct NDR.

Answer (score 1):

In fact,
(A) is also ill formed NDR, but compiler doesn't succeed to diagnose that.

Once `T` is fixed in class, there are no `Input` which makes the template valid.

It appears to works. As the expression becomes template dependent, the first phase is more complicated to check, and only the second phase (during the Subtitution) Fails but Is Not An Error (SFINAE applies).

Comment: Thank you. I’m not sure how to understand what sizeof is doing here that makes it work? Can you please explain that a bit?

Comment: `sizeof(Input)` depends of `Input`, so a condition like `sizeof(Input) == 4` has to wait to the instantiation with given `Input`. `sizeof (Input), false` is always `false` (but not so easy to demonstrate from compiler point of view (in general case)), but depends of `Input`. so compilers wait for instantiation where SFINAE might apply.

Comment: Thanks! is the code that works and is uncommented - well formed?

Comment: Both A and B make program ill formed NDR